# Falla de convergencia en ajuste de curvas por nls

Tags: r

estoy tratando de ajustar una curva sigmoidal a varios conjuntos de datos, por lo cual estoy usando este script:
plotPoints(MS ~ Dia, data = dataT1)

```
MST1 <- nls(y ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (x - d)))),
            data = dataT1,
            start = list(a = min(dataT1$y),
                         b = max(dataT1$y),
                         c = 1, d = median(dataT1$x)),
            trace = TRUE, algorithm = "port")

overview(MST1)
plotfit(MST1, smooth = TRUE)
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que con varios grupos de datos el script me funciona pero con otros no, dandome el siguiente error:

```
Error in nls(Nabs ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (Dia - d)))), data = dataT1NPK,  : 
  Convergence failure: false convergence (8)
```

y

```
Error in nls(Kabs ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (Dia - d)))), data = dataT1NPK,  : 
  Convergence failure: iteration limit reached without convergence (10)
```

¿A qué se podría deber esto?
Les dejo uno de los database que me da error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8srl24xmd7jw0v/Duduas_database.xlsx?dl=0

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisamos `?nls` podemos encontrar en las advertencias (Warning) que el algoritmo "port" todavía no está finalizado y hay que usarlo con precaución:

> The algorithm = "port" code appears unfinished, and does not even
>   check that the starting value is within the bounds. Use with caution,
>   especially where bounds are supplied.

Por consiguiente podemos dar uso de una función que lo reemplace: nlsLM. Lo podemos conseguir instalando el paquete `install.packages("minpack.lm")`

```
library(nlstools)
library(minpack.lm)

MST1 <- nlsLM(y ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (x - d)))),
            data = dataT1,
            start = list(a = min(dataT1$y),
                         b = max(dataT1$y),
                         c = 1, d = median(dataT1$x)),
            trace = TRUE, algorithm = "port")

overview(MST1)
plotfit(MST1, smooth = TRUE)
```

*** Respuesta ***

```
------
Formula: y ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (x - d))))

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
a -6.23e+01   1.64e+03   -0.04     0.97
b  1.21e+03   2.75e+05    0.00     1.00
c  7.27e-03   2.48e-01    0.03     0.98
d  4.08e+02   4.16e+04    0.01     0.99

Residual standard error: 14.2 on 14 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations till stop: 50 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
Reason stopped: Number of iterations has reached `maxiter' == 50.

------
Residual sum of squares: 2820 

------
t-based confidence interval:
         2.5%      97.5%
a -3.5894e+03 3.4649e+03
b -5.8934e+05 5.9176e+05
c -5.2374e-01 5.3827e-01
d -8.8712e+04 8.9528e+04

------
Correlation matrix:
         a        b        c        d
a  1.00000 -0.99653  0.99908 -0.99706
b -0.99653  1.00000 -0.99916  0.99998
c  0.99908 -0.99916  1.00000 -0.99941
d -0.99706  0.99998 -0.99941  1.00000
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ok ¿Pero qué solución o alternativa puede haber al problema?

Comment: Como sabrás , el algoritmo "port" fue hecho por la compañia estadounidense "Bell Labs". Que hoy en día no está invirtiendo en mejorar este algoritmo. O sea habrá que dar uso de otro algoritmo. Puedes dar uso de: `algorithm ="default"` . Ya que el algoritmo "port" tiene cierta cuasi aproximación al algoritmo de "Gauss-Newton". Fuente: http://www.bell-labs.com/our-research/publications/224275/

Comment: El algorithm = "default" fue lo primero que hice y en todos los casos me da el siguiente error: 
`Error in nls(Pabs ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (Dia - d)))), data = dataT1NPK,  : 
  singular gradient`
También probé con algorithm = "plinear" y me da error en todas.
Solamente el algorithm = "port" me dio resultado en algunas muestras.
¿Hay alguna forma de obtener la curva sin usar la función nls, o de modificarla para obtener la curva?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta. Espero vuestros comentarios.

Comment: Brillante, si bien me da un mensaje de advertencia de que el número máximo de interacciones es 50 me toma el modelo y me muestra los resultados.
Realmente agradesco mucho tu ayuda!!!

Comment: Fuente: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-better-nls/

Comment: @germanfernandez, recuerda que la forma de agradecer en SO es la aceptación de la respuesta y/o el voto positivo. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, disculpe, soy nuevo en la comunidad.

Comment: @germanfernandez, no te preocupes, todos empezamos igual. Suerte.

Comment: La solución que se me brindo funciono en todas las variables (de momento son 12) menos en 2 que me da el siguiente error
`Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates`.
Sospecho que es un problema de los datos estudiados ya que los dos se refieren al mismo parámetro. Igualmente dejo los datos por las dudas de que pueda tratarse de otro error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8srl24xmd7jw0v/Duduas_database.xlsx?dl=0
Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuéntame cómo conseguiste este error? Sería bueno que me facilites los datos para reproducir este error.